# Is it better to start with Sencha Touch 2, or Sencha Touch 1.x?

Tags: mobile, cordova, sencha-touch

I've recently built a demo application using PhoneGap, and I chose to try JQuery Mobile as a UI framework.  It was... okay.  I'd like to try out Sencha Touch now and see if I like it better.

As of now (mid-December '11), it appears that Sencha Touch 2 has been released as a preview, and has significant improvements in performance (which is a key ingredient for me).  However, it's missing some features, and doesn't seem to have many demos / tutorials yet on the Sencha website.

In the valuable opinion of SO's seasoned Sencha Touch developers (and by seasoned, at least in the mobile realm, I mean that you've at least played with it for a week or so), would you recommend I start with Sencha Touch 2 from the get-go, or go through the motions of learning 1.x and just upgrading to 2 later on?  What are the advantages / disadvantages of using "preview" versions of this and other frameworks, particularly when working within the ever-shifting world of mobile development?

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I created a few proof of concepts for my company in jQuery Mobile. While I personally love jQuery, jQM was not ready for a production environment if you wanted a slick, responsive, bug-free user interface. That was in the v1.0RC3 days. It is a stable release at the moment but I still feel the same way, hopefully future versions will address the shortcomings. I made this decision after running a number of benchmarks, a focus group and a pilot program(6 ppl). All said and done, I decided to evaluate ST.

Sencha Touch has the best UI, IMO. However, there is a strong learning curve with this framework. API documentation is complete and while there are tutorials lurking here and there, there is NOTHING that spells out the ST framework from start to finish. I often find myself searching in the depths for a brief glimpse of an explanation with no resolve. I find it frustrating that the Sencha team hasn't addressed this. I hear a lot about brushing up on **EXTjs** first as that **is the placenta of ST's birth**. (yes, I just said that) Truth is, if one has to learn another framework to utilize the one you are interested in, just to understand how it works, its a major fail. I'm not learning EXTjs just for ST...

For Sencha Touch, you should be versed in MVC, object oriented programming, debugging web technology and have a solid understanding of JavaScript.

Now the real question is 1.x or 2.x. Situations like this are highly debatable. Resource and cost analysis should be done on both versions to show how your development time increases if you were to port 1.x code to 2.x and any other overhead associated with learning curves, etc. So instead of give you my biased opinion, I'll just tell you what I did for my company (7k + employees).

My project needed to be at a certain milestone by a certain date and I certainly can't deploy something that isn't in production status. Simply meaning I cannot use a beta for anything substantial. As ST2.x is in the PR3 stage, it isn't ready for production. Not to mention a lot of key features of ST are currently missing from the ST 2.x release, though will be added in future releases as they progress to production stable.

I developed my app in 1.x because it was stable, has numerous examples and documentation available so I could produce an app **TODAY**. If I started in ST2, I wouldn't be able to finish the app. The API is not frozen, lacking full documentation, sparse examples, limited community resources and missing features. I can't wait for ST2(going to be great!) but can't risk my project over it.

Bottom line... if you need an app today, go with ST1, if you can hold off for another few months and have the time to make updates to your app as the ST2 API is frozen and features are added back in, then I would go that route. Cheers.

Comment: Wow, you definitely tapped right into the core of my question and addressed pretty much everything I could have hoped for.  Thank you!  With such a thorough response, I hope others aren't scared off of weighing in themselves, haha!  For now I'll start with 1.x, and hopefully gather enough knowledge of the learning process myself to be able to update this question later with my own answer, though I imagine this question won't be of much use past the release of ST2.

Comment: We are certainly aren't the only ones in the same boat.. glad I could help!

Comment: Fantastic response. Can you shed a little light on the features that are currently missing in 2.0 and are yet to be implemented?

Comment: @Joshua - I don't have a firm handle on a 1.x - 2.x feature comparison. I originally picked up this info just by reading their blog. Here is an excerpt from it "This is just a developer preview so we’re not quite feature complete yet. At the moment the main items missing from the release are multiple carousel animations, sortable tabs, draggables and history/deep linking support. These will all be coming back into the framework before general release." Have a look here for more information: http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-touch-2-developer-preview/

Comment: Looping back on this now that ST2 GA was released... If you haven't already, I would start all new projects in ST2. They really did an awesome job on it and it is way better than ST1. I had to spend some time migrating my ST1 apps but it was worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest learning Sencha Touch 2. I wasted a lot time working with Sencha Touch 1. Just before giving up - decided to try Sencha 2 - devel release 4. Much much easier to work with and learn.

Good luck
JRS

Comment: but i get white blank screen when i run sencha 2 app in my eclipse emulator ? am i missing any settings ?