# What Sencha Touch version should I be using for a new development?

Tags: sencha-touch, version, extjs

I was looking into using either jquery mobile or sencha touch to enhance a mobile web app I had been developing and after seeing some impressive Sencha Touch demos I decided it was the more refined framework.

Anyways, after looking at the Sencha Touch website I'm not sure which version I should be downloading, the current commercial version or the 2.0 developer preview release 3?

While it isn't fully complete yet, I don't want to spend time developing with version 1.1.1 and then have to migrate in 3-4 months time from now (not sure what the development timeline is so I may be way off).

I was hoping a Sencha touch developer would be able to provide some insight on what the best practice would be here.

Thanks

Also, I currently have the app developed in codeigniter with a more simplistic UI, are the two easy to integrate or not?

Comment: Possible duplicate - [Is it better to start with sencha touch 2 or sencha touch 1.x][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596307/is-it-better-to-start-with-sencha-touch-2-or-sencha-touch-1-x

Answer (score 0):

In my case has "Sencha Touch 2.0.0 Preview Release 3" only made ​​problems. Now I've installed the "Sencha Touch 1.1.1" and it works up to now everything. As long as I can still work with it to be seen.